# Syntax error with mutual recursion on a list in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I am using OCaml v 4.00.1.  I am trying to write a function using mutual recursion to take a list and return an int.  The int is the results of taking alternating elements of the list and adding and subtracting them from each other.  For example, the list [1;2;3;4] would results in 1 + 2 - 3 + 4 = 4.

My code is as follows:

```
let alt list =
  let rec add xs = match xs with 
    [] -> 0 
    | x::xs -> x + (sub xs)
  and sub xs = match xs with 
    [] -> 0
    | x::xs -> x - (add xs);;
```

OCaml throws a syntax error on the ;; at the very end of the code.  I am unsure where to start to figure out what this error actually is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you forgot to add `in ...` portion of the `let` binding – changes in **bold**

```
let alt list =
  let rec add xs =
    match xs with 
      | [] -> 0 
      | x::xs -> x + (sub xs)
  and sub xs =
    match xs with 
      | [] -> 0
      | x::xs -> x - (add xs)
  in
  add list
```

This will start the sequence with `+`, ie 1 **+** 2 - 3 ...

If you want it to start with `-` ...

```
...
in
sub list
```

We can swap `match` syntax for `function` and readability is improved here

```
let alt list =
  let rec add = function
    | [] -> 0
    | x::xs -> x + (sub xs)
  and sub = function
    | [] -> 0
    | x::xs -> x - (add xs)
  in
  add list
```

Comment: i think you're right!  i'll check it when i get home tonight.  thank you!

Comment: that worked, thank you!  where can i read about using function instead of match syntax?